# Omitting the types of the parameters

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell or ML it's perfectly fine to omit types of the arguments in a function:

```
fun add (x, y) = x + y (*ML*)
add x y = x + y -- Haskell
```

because it's clear from a context what the types of the parameters should be. Why isn't that the same in Scala?

```
def add(x, y) = x + y // error!
```

Comment: *Very* briefly - the OO nature of Scala complicates type inference, so Scala is (thus far) not able to perform as well as ML and Haskell in this regard - see the link given by @Tikhon for more.

Comment: Related: [Why is Scalas type inference not as powerful as Haskells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234095/why-is-scalas-type-inference-not-as-powerful-as-haskells)

Comment: Try: `def add[B](x:B,y:B)(implicit num: Numeric[B]):B = num.plus(x,y)`

Comment: @ajozwik, this is not type inference.

Comment: @Alex - but in scala you cannot write without knowledge about types. See implementation of List, Seq for sum, Ordered and other. Maybe you will find something more friendly

Comment: @ajozwik, why did you give me that example then?